# Not a function Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have just started using angular 2 and typescript. When I'm importing the class from .ts file is getting compiled successfully but throws an error

> Not a function _co.upchange

when using `(click)`.

**Update.ts**

```
export class Update {
  name:string;
}

export class Changeable {
  upchange (value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

**update.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Update } from './Update';
import { Changeable } from './Update';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  update:Update = {
    name:'Bhavya',
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There's no `update` method in your component class, hence the error.

Comment: You should also include the template code from `update.component.html` as this is likely where the error is originating from.

Comment: @Phix I just edited the post can you chek oncle

Comment: `upchange` is not called anywhere in the shared code. Please check if the object on which you are calling `object.upchange()` is of type `Changeable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
 update:Update={
 name:'Bhavya',
 }
```

Is defining an object with the *SHAPE* of your Update class ... but it is NOT an instance of the class.

If you plan to call methods on the object, you need to create an instance of the object, like this:

```
update = new Update();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.update.name = 'Bhavya';
  }
```

But as others have said, the method you are calling is in the Changeable class?

Consider changing the code as follows:

```
export class Update {
  name:string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  upchange(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
update = new Update('Bhavya');
```

But seeing the HTML where you are calling the `upchange` function would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

Define functions as methods in the class as shown with `upchange` above. Notice we do *not* have to use the `function` keyword.

Call the function as follows:

```
this.update.upchange('somevalue');
```

Call it using the *instance* variable, not the class name. If you want to call a method using the class name, use a static method. But note that static methods should not retain state.

See this for more information: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#821-instance-and-static-members

Comment: Also note: Classes are usually *things*. Consider renaming the class to represent the *thing*, such as `Customer` or `Contact`.

Comment: Thanks ... it worked... There is something i want to ask..... can i export the function from update.ts if so what would be the syntax..

Comment: It is already exported since it is by default a public method in an exported class. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm learning Typescript what i'm tying to do is define the function as object as we do in regular js synatx:  myfunction:function(){ //do someting } and the use it as classname.myfunction